# Build HTML5 video content, then play video on click event iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a content area that gets dynamically loaded with new content when you press the previous or continue buttons.  A simple example of html is:

```
<div id="contentArea"></div>
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li class="butPrev">Previous</li>
      <li class="butNext">Next</li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

What I used to do in iOS6 is have a mask over the content area on first load that I could click to trigger audio and video and then all other dynamic HTML5 videos would play.  I am not sure about iOS7, but iOS8 doesn't allow this.  I would have to do it for each page, which defeats the purpose of the mask and is a pain for a user.

As an alternative, I am trying to trigger the play of videos with the next button click.  The problem is that the next button captures the dynamic content, loads it into the content area and at that time needs to trigger the play, which iOS doesn't like.  Is there any way to wait until the content area is loaded, while staying within the click event so it doesn't get blocked? Here is what I am trying (I have stripped out the Ajax stuff):

```
var contentLoaded = false;

$('nav li').click(function(){
    contentLoaded = false;
    //load HTML with HTML5 video via Ajax
    //when done, sets contentLoaded = true
    triggerAutoplay();
});

function triggerAutoplay() {
    if (contentLoaded) {
       $('video[autoplay]').each(function(){
           if ($('this').attr('autoplay') != "false") {
               this.play();
           }
       });
    } else {
       setTimeout(triggerAutoplay,100);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to play() in the actual click. you might be able to the touchstart to load the video before click fires, but it depends on if the dynamic part is sync or not. does chnging the video "src" stop an already-playing video? i know it restarts, but does the new one play automatically, riding on the play() of the old one?

Comment: Once an audio/video tag is played once, it seems you can continue to call play on it and change the src after that. I do this with audio, but unfortunately the video is in different places and not always present in the content, so this method doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The play trigger has to be within the click function, so I have to set async to false so that the ajax completes before the function is call like:

```
$('nav li').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "whatever",
      async: false
   });
   triggerAutoplay(); 
});

function triggerAutoplay() {
   $('video[autoplay]').each(function(){
           if ($('this').attr('autoplay') != "false") {
               this.play();
           }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if i understand you right, but maybe you should call the play in the success of your ajax call like so:

```
$('nav li').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "whatever"
   }).done(function() {
      //do some stuff
      triggerAutoplay();
   }); 
});

function triggerAutoplay() {
   $('video[autoplay]').each(function(){
           if ($('this').attr('autoplay') != "false") {
               this.play();
           }
   });
}
```

Comment: That is what I would like to do, but the play is still blocked in iOS. The only way I see that can be done is if the async is set to false and have the play after the ajax function.